# How to exclude duplicate values / NULL values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, duplicates, conditional-statements

I hope that someone from you will be able to help me as I got stuck with a (silly) condition logic.
I am joining 2 temp tables.
The target is to see the Jobs, Tracking numbers, etc. (all actions) in one row always for one Consignee (Consignee Ref). In other words, to show all actions/data per Consignee Ref.
The issue I got is duplacated values. The problem is that the **Original Job (620X)** field can have assigned **Tracking_1** but it can be also **null**. Also the **Second Job (629X)** filed can have but do not need to have assigned the **Tracking** number/value. It can be also the case that both **Tracking_1** and **Tracking** are **NULL** for one **Consignee Ref**.
When I would exclude Jobs where **Tracking_1** or **Tracking** is **NULL**, then I will loose the Jobs that have no Tracking Numbers at all. So I used the code below, but then I am getting duplicates.

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp t1
INNER JOIN #Temp2 t2 on t1.[Consignee Ref] = t2.[Consignee Ref]
WHERE t1.[Tracking_1] is not null
ORDER BY [Original Job (620X)] asc
```

[image]

How can I make it that I will get rid of the unnecessary duplicates (an example marked in red)?
And at the same time not to loose  those jobs that have no Tracking Numbers?

I hope it makes sense.
Thank you very much in advance for any advise!

This is the entire code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp;

SELECT distinct
cne.[Consignee Ref], 
s.[Trial AWB] as [Original Job (620X)],
rl.[CarrierReference] as [Tracking_1],
CAST(st.[Sched Collection date] as date) AS [Collection Date],
CAST(st.[Act Del Date] as date) AS [Delivery Date],
s.[Clientaccountcode] as [Account Code]

into #Temp
FROM MKN_Reporting.dbo.shipment AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Month By JN Tb] AS b WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = b.[JobId]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Branch currency Tb] AS c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.BranchPrefix = c.[Branch Prefix] 
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Client group Tb] AS g WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[Clientaccountcode] = g.[Customer A/c]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Chargeto] AS cg WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = cg.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Shipper] AS sh WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = sh.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Cnee] AS cne WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = cne.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Country & Region Tb] AS r WITH (NOLOCK) ON sh.[Shipper Country code] = r.[Country Code]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Country & Region Tb] AS reg WITH (NOLOCK) ON cne.[Consignee Country code] = reg.[Country Code]
INNER JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Status] st ON COALESCE(s.ParentId, s.id) = st.Jobid
LEFT JOIN [CARRIERS_CHARGES] AS cc ON s.id = cc.JobId   
LEFT JOIN [RouteLegs] as rl on cc.RouteLegId = rl.id

WHERE [Clientaccountcode] in ('US429', 'MI1091')
--AND rl.[CarrierReference] is not null

-------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp2;

SELECT distinct
cne.[Consignee Ref], 
s.[Study Number] as [Study_],
s.[Site Number] as [Site No_],
s.[Trial AWB] as [Second (629X)],
rl.[CarrierReference] as [Tracking],
CAST(st.[Sched Collection date] as date) AS [Collection Date],
CAST(st.[Act Del Date] as date) AS [Delivery Date],
s.[Clientaccountcode] as [Account Code]

into #Temp2
FROM MKN_Reporting.dbo.shipment AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Month By JN Tb] AS b WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = b.[JobId]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Branch currency Tb] AS c WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.BranchPrefix = c.[Branch Prefix] 
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Client group Tb] AS g WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[Clientaccountcode] = g.[Customer A/c]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Chargeto] AS cg WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = cg.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Shipper] AS sh WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = sh.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Cnee] AS cne WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.[id] = cne.[jobid]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Country & Region Tb] AS r WITH (NOLOCK) ON sh.[Shipper Country code] = r.[Country Code]
LEFT JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Lookup Country & Region Tb] AS reg WITH (NOLOCK) ON cne.[Consignee Country code] = reg.[Country Code]
INNER JOIN MKN_Reporting.dbo.[Status] st ON COALESCE(s.ParentId, s.id) = st.Jobid
LEFT JOIN [CARRIERS_CHARGES] AS cc ON s.id = cc.JobId   
left JOIN [RouteLegs] as rl on cc.RouteLegId = rl.id    
WHERE [Clientaccountcode] in ('US1598')
--AND rl.[CarrierReference] is not null

---------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM #Temp t1
INNER JOIN #Temp2 t2 on t1.[Consignee Ref] = t2.[Consignee Ref]
WHERE t1.[Tracking_1] is not null
ORDER BY [Original Job (620X)] asc
```

Comment: Used query syntax looks like SQL Server (MS SQL)-relative, not MySQL-relative. Check your DBMS, re-tag if needed.

Comment: Provide a sample. CREATE TABLE for both tables (the columns excess for the task may be skipped), INSERT INTO with some sample data (5-10 rows per table is enough), desired result for this data, detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess OP is looking for some kind of field aggregation for T2.
With SQL Server 2017+, like in PostgreSQL,  you can now use `STRING_AGG` (same syntax than the Oracle `LISTAGG`.. "*Why did they not use the same keyword...*").

`STRING_AGG` will ignore null values from T2 and requires grouping if not *alone*. You have to add the other T1 and T2 required fields if any, but take care *for T2* that it can imply duplicates and may need aggregation too...

Here is an example with your provided TSQL :

```
SELECT t1.[Consignee Ref], t1.[Original Job (620X)], t1.[Tracking_1],
       STRING_AGG(t2.[Tracking],',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.[Tracking] ASC) Tracking_T2
  FROM #Temp t1
       INNER JOIN #Temp2 t2 on t1.[Consignee Ref] = t2.[Consignee Ref]
 WHERE t1.[Tracking_1] is not null
 GROUP BY t1.[Consignee Ref], t1.[Original Job (620X)], t1.[Tracking_1]
 ORDER BY t1.[Original Job (620X)] asc
```

**EDIT:** For previous SQL Server release (before 2017), you can achieve string aggregation with XML query :

**EDIT2:** Adding EXISTS clause to convey the INNER JOIN from the initial query.

```
SELECT t1.[Consignee Ref], t1.[Original Job (620X)], t1.[Tracking_1],
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.[Tracking]
                         FROM #Temp2 t2 
                        WHERE t1.[Consignee Ref] = t2.[Consignee Ref]
                        ORDER BY t2.[Tracking]
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, N'') Tracking_T2
  FROM #Temp t1
 WHERE t1.[Tracking_1] is not null
   AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM #Temp2 t2 WHERE t2.[Consignee Ref] = t1.[Consignee Ref])
 GROUP BY t1.[Consignee Ref], t1.[Original Job (620X)], t1.[Tracking_1]
 ORDER BY t1.[Original Job (620X)] asc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the SSMS does not recognized a built-in function name STRING_AGG

Comment: STRING_AGG is supported only since MSSQL17 and the related SSMS 14.+ with SMO 15.+. I guess your on a previous SQL Server release.  I'll edit the answer to add the FOR XML PATH corresponding way.

Comment: Edit done, it should work for your SQL Server release.

Comment: @AdélaŠkrábalová  Added an EXISTS clause to keep only t1 records that have at least one corresponding t2 records, as your initial query filter only #temp1 records having corresponding #temp2 records.